# Dynamic JSP tag files in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am using JSP tag files to add "widgets" to my application pages.

Is it possible to have an action associated with a JSP tag file, so it will be populated with dynamic content just like a normal page and then "injected" in some place?

Let's say I have tag file that I invoke like this: `<c:onlinemembers />`. It displays the list of online members. 
I need to have a way of populating it with dynamic data before it is displayed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a JSP to call the tag. Associate the JSP with an action that will be invoked via AJAX. The JSP can return only the fragment HTML necessary.

Comment: Take a look at what Apache tiles offers. As a template solution it is nice, it will not remove the need for ajax but you will be able to nicely break things up so you can see your components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: as pointed out by Alexandr, this is good on Struts 2.0.x, where Struts integrates Dojo tags. Since Struts 2.1.x, jQuery should be used instead (with similar mechanism).

All depends on your Struts2 version.

---

OR you can use the built-in Struts2/Dojo AJAX feature.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Scripts executed when loading the JSP:
      function configPage(){
        // Dojo topic function subscribing:
        dojo.event.topic.getTopic("myTopic").subscribe(null, "updateDivFunction");
      }

      function updateDivFunction(param1, param2){
        // Get the Div
        var myDiv = dojo.widget.byId("myDynamicDiv"); 

        // Set a new href to the AJAX action to call, 
        // which will return a partial JSP (a snippet),
        // as mapped normally in struts.xml...      
        myDiv.href = "loadDynamicDivAjax.do?param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2;

        // Force the div to reload with AJAX now.
        resultDiv.refresh();
      }

      function updateDivWrapper(param1, param2){
        // Publishing the topic now, will invoke the 
        // "updateDivFunction" set in configPage()...
        dojo.event.topic.publish("myTopic", param1, param2);
      }


    </script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:configPage();">
    <h1>My main JSP page</h1>

    <br/><br/>

    <s:div id="myDynamicDiv" theme="ajax" 
           loadingText="Loading..." 
           errorText="Errors occurred...">
    </s:div>

    <br/>

    <span>
        Click below links to load the DIV with DOJO 
        through an AJAX call, and different parameters.
    </span>

    <br/><br/>

    <a href="javascript:updateDivWrapper('1','2')">
        Update with param1=1 and param2=2
    </a>

    <br/><br/>

    <a href="javascript:updateDivWrapper('8','9')">
        Update with param1=8 and param2=9
    </a>
</body>
```

in Struts.xml you should map loadDynamicDivAjaxAction to returning a normal JSP snippet as a result. That's it...

Comment: "Built in" dojo? Really? Actually it is a plugin and Struts2 dojo plugin is deprecated. There are others javascript plugins for Struts2. For example http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/.

Comment: A shame we're stuck on 2.0.14... (where it IS built in, no separation between struts-tags and struts-dojo-tags) :S
Thanks for pointing it out, didn't knew it was deprecated.

Comment: But wouldn't eg. 10 requests at page load (let's assume that is how many "widgets" I have on the page) slow down the loading?

Answer (score 0):

I would either use Ajax and return the data as JSON and display using jQuery or create a custom JSP tag to do it. I'm not really fond of the latter. From your action just return JSON and using jQuery is a simple approach. Hope this helps.